# MySQL: Incorrect data type returns default row

Tags: mysql

I have this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM pffusers where uGoogleSecret=?;
```

`uGoogleSecret` is a `BIGINT`.  If I do:

```
SELECT * FROM pffusers where uGoogleSecret=00000000000000000;
```

this is not in the database and correctly returns 0 records. However, if I do:

```
SELECT * FROM pffusers where uGoogleSecret='hi';
```

this is also not in the database, yet it returns the first row in the table.  I want it to return 0 records.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value for uGoogleSecret in the returned row? Ideally MySQL should cast both `00000000000000000` and `hi` to `0`.

Comment: @Gurv you're a genius!

Answer (score 0):

Data type mismatch was converting string to 0 in mysql. 0 was my test `uGoogleSecret` .